# What it the Different from the HR Manager Users and HR Officer Users in Human Resource Concept in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have little bit confusion on user right for security access and key roles and functionality access for Human Resource concepts in Odoo.

I have too much confusion around the HR Officer Users and HR Manager Users from the Whole Human Resource Concepts in Odoo.

I have found in some case from HR manager Having the full access not more then the Administrator but less then access to the Officer Users In Human Resource Management  .

Can any one help me how both the users and its key roles played in whole Human Resources in Odoo ? and also

What is reason behind for add that two users into our Human resource flow Odoo ?

Answer (score 0):

there is a normal difference between this user access:

HR Manager:will have an access to the human resources configuration as well as statistic reports.

HR Officer: will have be able to approve document created by employees.

that's the thing nothing else.

Comment: no that's not much clear my doubts, you may clarify me in depth